What kind of connector should I use for a 13-pin BMS?
I'm trying to design a 13s 5p battery pack for an e-bike and am not sure about what types of connectors would be most appropriate between the BMS board and the battery for the sense + balance wires. I don't want the wires to come loose during operation, but I do want to be able to swap the BMS out easily. I'm considering using 5 BQ76940s (TI) to monitor each cell, so each connector only needs 13 pins.
I've considered JST and some molex connectors, but have no experience with either of them and don't know how well they'll hold up with vibrations.
Any suggestions?

What kind of an application is it -- indoor? outdoor? sealed? IPxx rated? Wire-to-board? Self-locking? Board-to-board? Bulkhead?

The standard connector for the balance input of a Li-ion BMS is a low-profile rectangular wire-to-board connector. For example, the JST PH with a 2 mm pitch. That is an acceptable solution for an e-bike.
If you wish to upgrade to automotive grade, consider instead an automotive connector. My company uses the JAE MX34 in its BMSs.


I'm trying to design a 13s 5p battery ...


... I'm considering using 5 BQ76940s (TI)

A 13S5P arrangement is possible but problematic:

The BMS costs 5 times as much
If any cell is weak, the performance of the entire battery is reduced.

The correct arrangement is 5P13S:

The BMS is cheap and easily obtainable off-the-shelf
If any cell is weak, the performance of the entire battery is minimally affected.

The difference:

Series first arrangement is bad (e.g., 13S5P): first a string of 13 cells in series, then 5 of those strings in parallel.
Parallel first arrangement is good (e.g., 5P13S): first a block of 5 cells directly in parallel, then 13 of those blocks in series.

